# Give an example of a function $f$ that is differentiable at $x=a$ such that $f'(a)\ne0$ but yet $f$ attains a relative extremum at $x=a$.

Tags: analysis

Give an example of a function $f$ that is differentiable at $x=a$ such that $f'(a)\ne0$ but yet $f$ attains a relative extremum at $x=a$.

By definition, the best I've gotten so far is using a function like $f(x)=x$ for $x=[0,1]$ since the maximum on that domain would be 1, and $f'(1)=1$, but I'm not sure if that's air tight (or even correct).

Comment: I don't think there's such a thing: to be differentiable at $\,x=a\,$ requires the function being defined in some open non-empty neighborhood of that point, and thus for the point to be an extremum one the derivative **must** be zero. One sided stuff isn't appliable here, imo.

Comment: Looks fine, and is probably the simplest case you'll be able to find.

Comment: @user65384 You should check your definition of derivative. Is it defined only on interior points?

Answer (score 1):

You know that if $f$ attains a maximum or minimum in a point internal to the domain where the function is differentiable then $f'=0$ in the point (Fermat's theorem). Hence the only possibility is the the point is on the boundary of the domain. Your example is hence correct.